Camera tracking movement is different after rendering
I'm very new to blender and am currently having trouble with a motion tracking shot. I have tracked the camera of a scene, and placed a modelled gun onto a table. In Cycles and Eevee the tracking looks perfect and stable in the viewfinder, however, after rendering in Cycles (in EXR sequence) the movement is completely off. The gun moves in roughly the right direction but kind of floats around and makes some seemingly random movements that should not exist. Any help is appreciated!
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ui0JUHE12k8&t=180s
[

Sorry, but assuming that the tutorial shows everything working correctly, just from a single screenshot we have almost no chance to find out what is wrong with your scene. The biggest problem when following tutorials is usually doing something slightly different than the tutorial, intentionally or accidentally, or missing some steps. Another problem is not using the same Blender version than the tutorial but depnding on the topic it might not matter much. Some error sources when the viewport result differs from render are often different visibilities/settings of objects or modifiers or both.

Thanks for this, what else could I screenshot that would help more in diagnosing the problem? There should be no visibility issues, as everything not visible in viewport is also set to not visible in render. What kind of object settings specifically do you think could be problematic?
